# Error catching mechanism in powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-4.0

Just a broad question here - is there a generic error catching mechanism in powershell? I'm having issue where by connection to MSSSQL server times out randomly via a powershell script and then re-running it would be fine.

Just want to know if there is any try-catch or similar error capturing in powershell available. Or if any one has better solution to catch connection timeouts let me know.

Thank you.
Zulfiqar

Comment: Did you try to search for, e.g. _Try Catch PowrShell_ on this board?

Comment: yes all soted thanks Clijsters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could use Try-Catch block.
Here is an example:

```
Write-Host "Disabling IP v6 - Reboot required after installation/update!" 
$breboot = $True
try
{
    New-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters\" -Name "DisabledComponents" -Value 0xffffffff -PropertyType "DWord" -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
    Write-Host ("IPv6 already disabled - no reboot required!")
    $breboot = $False
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the blogpost by kevin marquette: 
https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2017-04-10-Powershell-exceptions-everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know/.

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.